# Authorize.net payment issue

Tags: magento2, authorize.net

I have a multi-store in M2 version 2.3.3

The issue is with Authorize.net payment, when I click on place order I get an error:

"no such entity with cartId"

This is happening only if I set the payment option to authorize and capture if I set it to authorize only it's OK.

Also in the main store, it's working fine, the issue is with other stores.

Order is created in admin but stays on pending.

[image]

```
Error on screen:
<response>
<message>No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue</message>
<parameters>
<fieldName>cartId</fieldName>
<fieldValue>107</fieldValue>
</parameters>
<trace>
#0 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php(164): Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException::singleField('cartId', '107') 
#1 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository->getActive('107') 
#2 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->___callParent('getActive', Array) #3 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('107') 
#4 /var/www/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository/Interceptor.php(52): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getActive', Array, Array) 
#5 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Cart/CartTotalRepository.php(89): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->getActive('107') 
#6 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository->get('107') 
#7 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository\Interceptor->___callParent('get', Array) 
#8 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('107') 
#9 /var/www/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Cart/CartTotalRepository/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins('get', Array, Array) 
#10 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php(144): Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository\Interceptor->get('107') 
#11 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php(166): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement->getPaymentInformation('107') #12 [internal function]: Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement->getPaymentInformation('E8MYixrI58pSjig...') 
#13 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
#14 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy)) 
#15 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#16 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array) 
#17 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#18 /var/www/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array) 
#19 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(137): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#20 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() 
#21 /var/www/magento2/pub/index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor)) 
#22 {main}
</trace>
</response>
```

Thank you,

Eran Greenwald